# No source code cpp file for turtlebot

Tags: ros, c++, source, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Everyone,
I have tried to run two turtlebots independently on the same simulation and I just use the model from the tutlebot simulator (hydro) to create two copies using different namespaces, robot1 and robot2. I spawned two and can input velocities independently using the rostopic pub[] command but the problem is that i just got one odom(nav_msgs/Odometry) topic no separate by namespace. Some people posted the solution for this problem by changing the "gazebo_ros_create.cpp" file. I searched for this file in my PC but I couldn't find it. Please can somebody tell where I can find this source file in my PC?
I am using Hydro version with turtlebot simulator files.

Thanks alot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/154876/no-source-code-cpp-file-for-turtlebot/) by [Robert1](https://answers.ros.org/users/12391/robert1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2014-04-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you installed ros with apt-get, you will only have binary packages and no source code. You will have to create your own catkin workspace and include the source. It is in the `create_gazebo_plugins` package. To find the source the following command can help, which outouts rosinstall syntax that can be merge into a workspace with `wstool`.

```
roslocate info create_gazebo_plugins --distro hydro
```

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robert1](https://answers.ros.org/users/12391/robert1/) on 2014-04-19**:
Thanks a lot Demmeln!! I got it

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-20**:
If your Problem is solved, Plesse Mark an answer an accepted to indicate that to everyone. Thanks :-).

**Comment by [Robert1](https://answers.ros.org/users/12391/robert1/) on 2014-04-24**:
Demmeln, I installed turtlebot from source using:

> cd ~/turtlebot
> wstool init src https://raw.github.com/turtlebot.. rosinstall -j8
> source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash
> rosdep install --from-paths src -i -y
> catkin_make
> I made some changes but i don't know how to recompile using catkin_make help